# Nginx and multiple applications

Tags: nginx, directory

I am new to nginx, and here what I am trying to achieve :

- I have only  one domain name.
- I want to have several applications, accessible with something like :
  mydomain.com/app1
  mydomain.com/app2
  etc

So I ended up with a configuration like this :

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mydomain.com;

        location ~ /site1 {
            alias /srv/http/site1;
            index home.html;
        }

        # fallback if no application is passed as argument
        location / { 
          alias /srv/http/default;
          index index.html;
        }
}
```

However, I only got 403 error.

My directories are owned by the nginx user (http) and, to be sure it was not a permission issue, I chowned everything to 777 (just to test, dont worry ;) ).

Any idea ?

---

EDIT:
Thanks to Florin Asavoaie, I got something working :

What did the trick :

- remove the ~ in location
- replace the 2nd alias with root (however, the first alias seems to be needed ..).

So I have this conf. working :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location /site1 {
            alias /srv/http/site1;
            index home.html;
    }

    location / {
          root /srv/http/default;
          index index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried symlink?

Comment: Don't do this. Use subdomains instead.

Comment: I cant't use subdomain, unfortunately. This is not "my" domain name and I don't have the permission to add a subdomain.

Nam phung : what do you mean ?

Comment: i dont see configuration directive "root", did you omitted it or it is just missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check the error log, it will show you why it outputs 403 error.
2. Alias does replacements on URL, not on server paths. Use `root` directive instead for what you want to do.
3. Remove the ~ in the location definition, aka `location /site1` instead of `location ~ /site1`, it has better performance and can avoid some other kind of issues. Only use ~ when you need regex.